# Kind vs the adjective kindly

Tags: differences

When l was reading a Pokemon book, I saw this expression "This calm and kindly pokemon is slow to anger, …". 
I'd like to ask you whether "kind" and "kindly" as an 
adjective are almost same or not. If there're some differences,could you tell me about that?

Answer (score 2):

From Longman *Dictionary of Contemporary English*, third edition 2000:

> **Kindly** is either the adverb of **kind**: *He kindly opened the door for me*, or an adjective with a slightly different meaning from **kind** which is much less comon: *She is a kindly person*.
>
> The adjective **kindly** describes a person's general character. **Kind** may also do this, but often describes someone's behaviour at one particular moment: *It was kind of you to help me*. |*She's often kind to me* (NOT kindly).

In essence, they claim that **kindly** wouldn't be used for someone who had done an isolated, or even frequent, acts of kindness. They really need to deserve it. ;)

Comment: +1.  Compare "sick" and "sickly".